# Problemas building cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, build

Using latest android studio sdk version, when i `cordova build android` a ionic project, i get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /home/jacsjr/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

ANDROID_HOME is pointing to the android-studio Sdk folder, but `/tools/templates`, is missing.

I already tried some awnsers here on stack overflow, with no lucky.

Downloading and replacing tools folder does not work.

How can i install correctly install gradle?

EDIT 1:

[/using platform android@6.2.1](https://ibb.co/dgUdkk)
[/using platform android@6.2.2](https://ibb.co/mumfy5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download:

- Windows no installer:
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip
- MacOSX:
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip
- Linux:
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip

Extract and place on `/Android/Sdk/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed in the new cordova, did you try:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@6.2.2
```

Comment: Error: cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function